# powershell/sqlplus error SP2-0042: unknown command " ■@" - rest of line ignored

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I am running this command in powershell:

```
sqlplus system/passwd@mydb  @my_sql
```

I have tried it with and without backticks and various other versions I found via Google. I keep getting an error when the command is passed off to sqlplus and have been unsucessful in finding the fix.  Hopefully someone here can help out?

The error I get is:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SP2-0042: unknown command " ■@" - rest of line ignored.
```

So I am sucessfully connecting to the database but there is an extra character being passed to sqlplus in front of the '@'.    " ■@"  in notepad++  looks like " ¦@"

Answer (score 2):

If you created your SQL command file using a redirect (> or >>) in powershell - like:

**myProgram > mySQL.out** 
and then run it like:
   
**&sqlplus  mypw/myuser@mydb.xyz.com "@mySQL.out"**

Powershell may have saved the output file in UTF-16 format, which Sqlplus does not like.
(You can confirm by creating the exact same file by hand and then comparing it - byte count will be off and in KDiff you'll get message to the effect that the text is equal, but the files are not binary equal).

To fix - you need to do two things: :

1. Add some blank lines to the top of your SQL commands - Powershell will still write a BOM (Byte Order Mark) there and it looks like it's pretty hard to get it to avoid that - but sqlplus will just go by it, albeit giving an error - but will move on to the rest of your code OK.
2. And then run this command in powershell before creating your file: **$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'**

See [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

I received this error: 

 SP2-0042: unknown command " ■S" - rest of line ignored.
and this fixed that - or at least I was able to run it.  You can also just cut and past it from one window into another using Notepad++ and that will solve the BOM and encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

Update Problem Solved.  This turned out being "not seeing the trees through the forest".   I have been using these sql scripts for several years without issue called from a bash script.   When I tried converting the bash script to powershell  and ran into issues I blamed it on powershell.  However; it turned out there was something corrupt in the sql file itself.  There were no obvious errors when looking at the file in notepad++ even with show all symbols clicked and it was ANSI format.  I determined it was the sql file itself when I manually ran sqlplus from a cmd window I still had the same error I was getting with powershell.  I rewrote the script and saved it and the problem was fixed.  I should have manually ran the script on day one and I probably could have resolved sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My issue was caused because the script file was saved as unicode. I don't know if this will help you or not, but here is how I fixed it:

Edit the script with notepad. Click File -> Save As. Change type from Unicode (or whatever) to ANSI, and save.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions

Try the invoke operator:

```
&sqlplus system/passwd@mydb @my_sql
```

Try start-process:

```
start-process -NoNewWindow -FilePath sqlplus -ArgumentList @"
system/passwd@mydb @my_sql
"@
```

Comment: Update: I tried both methods suggested and the error still occurred.  Interestingly I am seeing the same problem when running from a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I had typical problem. The message was: 
unknown command "and" - rest of line ignored.
The reason was an empty string in code.
e.g.
select ... 
from ...
where ...
[empty string]
and ... < here was an error message

Answer (score 0):

use as following

```
sqlplus -s system/passwd@mydb  "@my_sql";
```

Answer (score 0):

***Context***

FWIW: My sqlplus client (12.2.0.1.0) triggered the error when encountering a line-initial '#' character in the supplied sql script.

***Remedy***

Add a single blank as the first character of the offending line. If the data is part of plsql code or a sql statement, ie. inside a string literal spanning multiple lines, wrap the literal with the `UNISTR(.)` function and reference the crosshatch by `\0023` (its utf8 hex code) (if db charset and national charset are al32utf8) or compose it from partial strings linked with `||chr(35)||`.

***Note***

There may be a setting for sqlplus to change the observed behavior. I have not explored this route.