# How to run this query on Oracle Developer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, oracle11g

I have this query as a part of powershell script and it runs ok on Sql server but fails on Oracle

```
select case when OBJECT_ID (N'INTERFACE_DEFINITION', N'U') is null then 0 else 1 end
```

Here is error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Is there some change required to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when 'a' > 'b' then 0 else 1 end
from DUAL;
```

> The DUAL table is present in every Oracle database. This special table
>   contains just one column. The column is named DUMMY, and it has a
>   datatype of VARCHAR2(1). The DUAL table contains only one row. That
>   row has a value in DUMMY of ‘X’.
>
> The purpose of DUAL is simple—to have
>   something to run a SELECT statement against when you don’t wish to
>   retrieve any data in particular but instead simply wish to run a
>   SELECT statement to get some other task accomplished.

Verifying that an object exists:

```
OBJECT_ID (N'INTERFACE_DEFINITION', N'U')
```

In Oracle you may use this query:

```
select count(*) from all_objects where object_name = 'INTERFACE_DEFINITION';
```

`all_objects` doesn't necessarily shows you all the objects in the database. It only shows you the objects on which a current user has any priviledges.

Comment: I'm getting Unknown command error and it doesn't say what is wrong exactly. I tried SYS.ALL_OBJECTS as well. I'm under user/schema/db called VTassure_dbo

Comment: @Hassan Gulzar What command have you tried? In order to check that an object exists you just need to run "select count(*) from all_objects where object_name = 'INTERFACE_DEFINITION';"

Comment: I tried 'select count(*) from all_objects where object_name = 'INTERFACE_DEFINITION';' on my account and the system account. Same result

Comment: @Hassan Gulzar Maybe there are some special characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631901/powershell-sqlplus-error-sp2-0042-unknown-command-%E2%96%A0-rest-of-line-ignored